# passing parameter with JQuery cluetip anchor

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am using JQuery for the first time and need help.

When i click on a anchor tag it calls a html div and shows up a popup(JqueryCluetip Plugin)

```
<a class="tips" href="#kt" rel="#kt" title="Kate Thompson">more info...</a>
```

I have this cluetip function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.tips').cluetip({
    cluetipClass: 'rounded',
    dropShadow: false,
    showtitle: false,
    positionBy: 'mouse',
    local: true,
    hideLocal: false,
    sticky: true,
    width: 410,
    closeText: 'Close'
});
```

});

Now my question is i want to pass parameter called userid to the anchor tag so that the popup shows differnet data based on input paramter. (Basically i have to pass that id to a backing bean and get the corresponding user details for that id and show it up in the popup.)
Please let me know how can i perform this task.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an arbitrary attribute to the element called 'userid' and get it out of the anchor object when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. Please let me know what exactly yo mean by an arbitary attribute?

Comment: Sure. It means just add an attribute that you name, such as 'userid'.
like this:
<a href="#" userid="[userid here]">link</a>
Now you can access the 'userid' attribute in jQuery like this:

var userid = $( a ).attr( 'userid' );

I hope this helps.